# How to get the total number of Wordpress Posts from an Author ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, wordpress-theming

I've been scouring everywhere and can't seem to find this. I know the WP variable within the loop can use `$post_count` but I'm writing from an external function. I've set `global wp_query` so I should be able to pull out the number, and I have the user IDs as well.

Any help would be more than appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at wp-includes/author-template.php. It includes various functions for pulling author data for display in a theme.

In this case, I think you are looking for count_user_posts($userid). If you are retrieving more than just post counts, you may want to create another instance of WP_Query().

Comment: perfect! Really appreciate it man. can't believe this wasn't anywhere in Google...